# Can $\mathbb{Z}^2$ be a subgroup of $\mathrm{PSU}(1,1)$?

Tags: group-theory, complex-analysis

Is there a subgroup of $\mathrm{PSU}(1,1)$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (as a group, ignoring the topology)?

Comment: Yes, as for every Lie group of dimension $\ge 1$. Such groups always contain an isomorphic copy of $S^1$ or $R$ and such groups contain free abelian subgroups of every rank  $\le$ continuum.

Comment: Or, maybe you actually mean "discrete subgroup", in which case the answer is "of course not".

Comment: @studiosus I meant only the group structure, not the topology. Can you please make your first comment into an answer? I don't know a thing about Lie groups so please keep it simple.

Comment: Is $\operatorname{PSU}(1, 1)$ even non-trivial? One-by-one matrices quotiented out by the diagonal. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $PSU(1,1)$ is isomorphic to the group $PSL(2,{\mathbb R})$: The former is the group of holomorphic automorphisms of the open disk of complex dimension 1 and the latter is the group of holomorphic automorphsims of the upper half-plane in the complex plane. The group is real 3-dimensional, it contains subgroups isomorphic to the additive group of real numbers (say, linear-fractional transformations $z\mapsto z+c, c\in {\mathbb R}$ in the upper half-plane model). The latter contains ${\mathbb Z}^2$: For instance, the subgroup generated by $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$. In fact, it is a good exercise to check that the additive group of real number contains the free abelian group of every cardinality at most continuum!